# numpy diag instruction,without touch the first and last element

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am looking for similar python instructions of following Matlab code,to construct an specific function over diagonal , without touching first and last element on main diagonal?

S = diag([0; 1 ./(1-x(2:N).^2); 0]);

how can i create this through python numpy? you may know diag in python has only two control items , not three which is mentioned in here.

thanks

Comment: Worse case you can always "read" the 2 values to preserve before overwriting them with themselves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ist no special `diag` with three arguments in matlab either. Instead this is called array concatenation in matlab.

You can do the same with python:

```
S = numpy.diag(numpy.hstack([0, 1/(1-x[1:N])**2, 0]))
```